# File Attribute is read only when its folder is read only and the file is not

Tags: c++, winapi, file

Anyone has any idea??
GetFileAttributes returns 32 (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE).
The file is C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, as 32 != FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE (should be 33)

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx

Take a look at this. Response 32 is only FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE. So your code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Which of the following is your situation?

1) [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx) returns 33 (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE)

or

2) [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944(VS.85).aspx) returns 32 (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE)

If the hosts file does not have the read only attribute, and GetFileAttributes does not return  INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES then you can trust it's return value.   So if the file actually doesn't have the read only attribute, then you have situation #2 above.

Answer (score 0):

It returns 33 (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE).
The hosts file ISN'T read only, but it is the return value.